# Why use preferredLayoutAttributesFitting and systemLayoutSizeFitting with self sizing collection view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on simple collectionView , its cell have tow UILabel (title and body).

The title is single line , and the body is multiline.

- Each label has constraint (from top to bottom).
- I add width constraint to contentView of cell
- I add estimatedItemSize to collectionViewLayout of collectionView

In the result the collectionView cell become self sizing according to body label text.

Then why use **preferredLayoutAttributesFitting** and **systemLayoutSizeFitting** if all things done using autolayout